# Selenium won't load specific webpages on bet365

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from bet365 for basketball odds however I am encountering where certain leagues webpages wont load even when simply just loading the page and not automating anything else. It is very irregular as to which leagues will load and which won't but for a large portion of the leagues it is displaying the message "Sorry, this page is no longer available. Betting has closed or has been suspended." - I am fairly new to web scraping so am not using any tools to hide the fact it is an automated script so I'm unsure if the site is flagging for bot activity but then I'm unsure why some pages would still load if that was the case.

I am simply just using chromewebdriver and driver.get() links like bet365.com/#/AC/B18/C20814074/D48/E1453/F10 bet365.com/#/AC/B18/C20604387/D48/E1453/F10/
Both work however other links:
bet365.com/#/AC/B18/C20815826/D48/E1453/F10/
bet365.com/#/AC/B18/C20816919/D48/E1453/F10/
Don't work despite being near identical pages

Just looking for some insight into why certain leagues would be blocked and if there is any way to work around it.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post your code here, so I can test it and verify the problem you are getting.

Comment: But as a general rule, some sites are not very web-scrapper friendly, so you need to dig in to find out exactly what is preventing the correct page source from loading.

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen any tips on how to approach this?